# PHP within JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have the following code:

```
  private function html_Headers()
    {
        $data = '
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getOptions(chosen){
    var selbox = document.myform.selectport;
  selbox.options.length = 0;
  if (chosen == "1") {
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option("-----------------","0");
    }


    }
    </script>

    </head>';
```

I'm trying to run some php mysql queries within the getOptions() JS function. I tried writing  tags but it didn't work. Does anyone see the problem here? Note that this is within a PHP class file.

Comment: I've spotted the problem: Your code is incomplete. Also.. You cannot directly run any serverside code (PHP) within a HTML document (JS), without sending a request to the server.

Comment: Missing at least the HTML opening tag

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786640/passing-data-from-php-to-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript is executed on the client, while PHP is interpreted on the server. 
That means: when the javascript is executed, your code is running already on the client side and PHP - Code is going to be pretty useless.

What you can do, is calling an PHP-file with a function over an AJAX-Call and parse the result back to the client. After this, you can do anything with the returned data, but you'll have to do it within JavaScript.

For AJAX-Calls, I usually use jQuery, because the calls are easy and browser differences are handled already for you.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",         // POST or GET
  url: "query.php",     // the php-file, including your mysql query
  data: "name=John&location=Boston",  //data sent to the server (in this case as post-param)
  success: function(data){
    //function executed, when the call succeeds. variable data is the data returned from your php
  }
});
```

Of course, you can make AJAX-Calls without using jQuery, maybe you should have a look at [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/xmlhttp.html)